# make a column automatic so it can increase by one every time a new record in entered

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I want to make AUTO_PROJECT_ID automatic so every time a new record in entered into the table it will give an automatic id.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE Table PUBLIC "-//EAME/TABLE MAINTENANCE -               TABLE" "Table.dtd">

     <Table Name="STRAT_STRATEGY_PROJECTS"
   Confidentiality="Non-confidential"
   Connection="DXP3"
   Owner="USERINPUT"
   DisplayRows="30" > 

 <DownloadableFormat name="Excel"/>

     <Column Name="AUTO_PROJECT_ID"
      Label="Internal Project ID"
      Required="True"
      ReadOnly="True"
      Key="True" />
```

Comment: Then you'll have to ask the author of whatever this XML format is how you specify that. This doesn't look like anything standard.

Comment: Don't konw if a sequence is callable out of this xml construct

Answer (score 0):

If it's Oracle database, as your tag suggested, then you should create a sequence and a trigger on your table to insert sequence value (if you want to use sequence value only if no other value is specified for ID, then use the line in comment inside the trigger):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_sequence
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON your_table
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- :NEW.id := NVL (:new.id, your_sequence.NEXTVAL);
    :NEW.id := your_sequence.NEXTVAL;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what part your XML needs to play in this, but from the database side you can just create the table something like this:

```
create table strategy_projects
( auto_project_id  integer generated always as identity constraint strpr_pk primary key
, project_name     varchar2(10) );
```

(requires Oracle 12.1 or later - for older versions you could use a trigger or explicitly use a sequence in whatever performs inserts into the table.)